# Advantage to calling PetscInitialize on a sub communicator

Tags: mpi, petsc

I was wondering if anybody knew any reason why it might be advantageous to call PetscInitialize on a subcommunicator?  For example, I have a problem that I am running on 4 cores, but only two of them need to utilize Petsc.  I can call PetscInitialize on a subcommunicator including only those two processes by setting

`PETSC_COMM_WORLD=mySubCommunicator`

but couldn't I just initialize it on `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and only call Petsc routines on the subcommunicator?  The reason I am asking is that it would simplify my code to just initialize on `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, but I wouldn't want to suffer any negative consequences as a result.  Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine as long as you do not call any collective operation on `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` with the subset of ranks. The only functions that do that implicitly that I could find were `PetscMallocDump`, `PetscMPIDump` and some `PetscLog*`. You also have to call `PetscFinalize` on all ranks.